# sudo to allow apt-get install of remote packages, but forbidding arbitrary commands

Tags: debian, docker, sudo, apt-get, sudoers

I'm looking for a way to allow a user to install (only remote) packages via `apt-get` (or another mechanism?) but not allow them to run arbitrary commands as root.

I can get *some* of the way there via /etc/sudoers. Say I have this in my /etc/sudoers file

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
john ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt,/usr/bin/apt-get
```

Then John appears limited to run `apt` and `apt-get` via `sudo`. But... there do seem to be ways to escape `apt-get` to a shell as root (https://blog.ikuamike.io/posts/2021/package_managers_privesc/):

- Type `sudo apt-get changelog apt` and hit enter
- Type an exclamation mark `!` and hit enter
- You’re now in the shell as root and can do anything

Or run the below:

```bsh
sudo apt update -o APT::Update::Pre-Invoke::="/bin/bash"
```

If it makes any difference, this is in Docker

---

Now posted at https://serverfault.com/q/1089874/166779, since I think that's the more appropriate site

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt, so the user would be use `sudo` to run this script, but no others.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# This script wraps `apt update` and `apt install`, but attempts to forbid
# arbitrary commands being able to be run by the user as root. It exists
# because allowing the user to `sudo apt` would allow
# `sudo apt changelog apt`, which runs `less` which then would allows the
# user to escape into the shell.

# But, full access to `apt update` and `apt install` still cannot be given,
# since there are 3 ways they can be used to run arbitrary commands
#
# 1. Via options in the APT_CONFIG environment variable
# 2. Via command line options, such as '-o' to specify scripts to run
# 3. Via a local package that contains custom install script(s)
#
# So this script attempts to forbid the 3 above possibilities

# 1. Clear any options in the APT_CONFIG environment variable
export APT_CONFIG=''

# 2. and 3. Forbid command line options or local packages
for var in $*
do
   if [[ ${var::1} == "/" || ${var::1} == "." || ${var::1} == "-" ]]
   then
     echo "E: It's forbidden to install a local package or pass an option"
     exit 1
   fi
done

# Update, and install requested packages
apt update
apt install -y $*
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).